# Como criar rotas, que aceite somente os valores permitidos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como faço para que :status aceite somente valores permitidos?

```
# routes.rb
get '/para_:status(/:opcao1)(/:opcao2)', to: 'search#index', :as => :search
```

Atualmente o :status aceita qualquer coisa que eu enviar.

Desejo que o :status seja somente: ativado ou desativado.

Tem como fazer um espécie de :status in(ativado, desativado)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para fazer isso usando expressão regular, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
# routes.rb
get '/para_:status(/:opcao1)(/:opcao2)', to: 'search#index', as: :search, constraints: { status: "(ativado|desativado)" }
```

Tem que vir dentro da opção *constraints*, que é um *hash*, onde você coloca o parâmetro, apontando para a expressão regular que ele aceita.

Essa expressão que eu fiz é a correta para o seu caso.

Se a *url* for **/para_ativado** ou **/para_desativado**, a rota é identificada, e chama o *controller* para dar continuidade. Se a *url* for **/para_blablabla**, retorna página não encontrada.

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo!